# Site feito para idosos? Existe alguma boa pratica para construir páginas para idosos?

Tags: html5, ux, acessibilidade, ui

Estou com uma dúvida, meio subjetiva, como quase tudo em UX. Mas vou partir de um cenário factível. Imagine o site do INSS, que supõem-se que é um site feito para idosos, pessoas que já se aposentaram, por idade ou invalidez. Pessoas que podem em grande parte apresentar problemas de acessibilidade.

Normalmente só vemos otimizações para pessoas cegas ou com problemas de visão. Mas além de aumentar o tamanho da fonte, e/ou ter algum artifício de alto contraste. Existem outras técnicas que possam facilitar a vida de indivíduos com limitações de idade, como problemas pessoas sem firmeza nas mãos, pessoas com dificuldades cognitivas, etc.

Quais práticas UX podemos adotar na UI e de forma geral para facilitar o acesso e inclusão de usuários da terceira idade? Existem boas praticas para isso?

Quais técnicas e conceitos podem ser adotados para tratar a interface web e mobile para pessoas com idade avançada? Quais pontos devemos levar em consideração para deixar uma página acessível para esse público?

*Sei que a resposta pode ter um pouco de opinião, mas a intenção é levantar requisitos e técnicas de desenvolvimento e interface que possam melhorar a UX desse público*

Comment: "*limitações de idade*", você pode chegar aos 60, no máximo.

Comment: Talvez algo como deixar os textos simples e intuitivos? Sem palavras e interações complicadas. Algo parecido com um site para crianças.

Comment: Tudo depende no ambiente em que tal idoso vive. Muitos possuem muitas dificuldades de acessar qualquer tipo de tecnologia.  Pois boa parte cresceu livre de muitas tecnologias. Pensar em idosos desse tipo, seria como pensar em algo que com quantos menos cliques, melhor. Acredito nisso baseando-me nos idosos que conheço, porém sem que muitos ja possuem bastante acesso a tecnologia por incentivo de outras pessoas.

Comment: @ArthurAbitante sim essas são algumas das preocupações que eu tb gostaria de saber como tratar

Comment: Começar com um modal bem grande dizendo "Qualquer dúvida nos pergunte no número X" e ter alguém sempre para atender, se possível, de graça a ligação (para quem liga)

Comment: @Costamilam isso é muito a cara do meu pai haha

Comment: Para facilitar a utilização de interfaces mobile por pessoas sem firmeza nas mãos ou com tremedeira, eu optaria por aumentar o tamanho dos botões, removeria funcionalidade de clicar e arrastar, de deslizar ou que utilize dois dedos ao mesmo tempo (tipo funcionalidade de zoom). Imagino que seja dificultoso para essas pessoas realizar essas ações em telas de celular, que geralmente não são muito grandes.

Comment: @DiegoAguiar obrigado pelas observações, são ponto interessantes mesmo!

Comment: É um cenário que acredito ser um pouco difícil, pois esta é uma situação recente em que se tem a criação de produtos voltado especificamente para este público. Porém acho que algumas das opções de acessibilidade trazidos no “menu acessibilidade” do Android 9 poderiam servir de base e serem adaptadas,  tais como: 1–Selecionar para ouvir; 2–Falar itens exibidos na tela; 3–Conversão de texto em voz; 4–Tamanho da fonte; 5–Tamanho da exibição; 6–Ampliação; 7–Ponteiro do mouse grande; 8–Remover animações; 9–Atraso ao pressionar; 10–Legendas; 11–Texto em alto contrate; 12–Inversão de cores ...

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira são pontos fundamentais, acho que vc poderia arriscar uma resposta ;). Se conseguir alguns exemplo de aplicações de alguns desses pontos, algum link de referencia ou *case*, ou mesmo algum estudo, uma resposta mais bem desenvolvida seria interessante pra comunidade, mas desde já agradeço pela dica.

Comment: Existem as diretrizes da W3C para acessibilidade. Isso tanto para quem tem algum tipo de deficiência ou idade mais elevada. Seguem os links.
Versão em português: https://www.w3.org/Translations/WCAG20-pt-br/
Versão em inglês: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/

Comment: Para idosos, como muitos têm dificuldade com tecnologia e baixa visão, consideraria utilizar uma fonte um pouco maior e com passo a passo bem mais definidos o possível. Dê preferência a acessos rápidos e design estruturado Você encontra algumas referências aqui:
https://medium.com/@titerceiraidade/acessibilidade-de-interfaces-digitais-para-a-terceira-idade-60299f8f3bdd https://g1.globo.com/economia/tecnologia/blog/ronaldo-prass/post/2019/02/20/aplicativos-para-idosos-simplificam-o-uso-do-celular.ghtml https://www.toptal.com/designers/ui/ui-design-for-older-adults

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Inicialmente é interessante separar as *personas* e os problemas de acessibilidade para serem abordados:

1. Problemas de visão
2. Problemas cognitivos
3. Problemas motores

Os três problemas acima são comuns na senilidade e podem ter soluções que ajudem essas pessoas a terem uma experiência no seu site ou aplicativo.

## Problemas de visão

### Contraste e nitidez

Evite tons cinzas e mudanças de cor delicadas, pois há uma dificuldade em perceber esses gradientes. Os elementos devem ser descomplicados e compreensíveis para que não se misturem com a cor de fundo. Tome cuidado com o baixo constraste, pois gera dificuldade para leitura.

Precisa-se garantir de que há contraste e nitidez suficiente. É recomendado não ter muitos efeitos de *blur* ou similares.

[image]

Existem [serviços](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) para checar o nível de contraste de cor da sua página, verificando se está dentro do padrão estabelecido pelo [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/Translations/WCAG20-pt-PT/).

### Cor

Com a idade, é mais difícil distinguirmos as cores umas das outras. A percepção também [fica um pouco mais amarelada](https://casa.abril.com.br/bem-estar/visao-dos-idosos-e-amarelada/).

> O cristalino [dos idosos] fica mais denso e absorve mais os azuis, e, assim, ele passa a enxergar mais amarelo. [(fonte)](https://casa.abril.com.br/bem-estar/visao-dos-idosos-e-amarelada/)

Em sua página ou aplicativo, opte por cores distintas e não muito próximas em matiz.

Também, não confie na cor para dar informação. Se você tem uma barra vermelha para indicar um erro, talvez precise de mais indicações, como um texto ou ícone.

[image]

Como de constraste, existem também [simuladores de daltonismo](http://colororacle.org) para você testar sua página.

### Tamanho

Preste atenção na escolha da fonte e tamanho que irá fazer. Lembre-se de manter consistência e não usar fontes demais.

[Fontes com serifa](https://composergrafica.com/blog/por-que-usar-fonte-com-serifa/) podem ser uma boa escolha, já que são as mais comuns em jornais e revistas.

> Fontes com serifa provocam a ideia de texto mais fluido e muitos designers defendem que esse tipo é ideal para diferenciar as palavras em um texto (por isso muitos jornais e revistas usam letras, principalmente no título, com serifa). Sabe-se que o leitor não lê um texto letra a letra, e sim palavra por palavra. Nesse contexto, ter uma fonte que se destaca com serifa parece ser mais atraente à nossa percepção. [(fonte)](https://composergrafica.com/blog/por-que-usar-fonte-com-serifa/)

## Problemas cognitivos

### Consistência

Um dos maiores problemas cognitivos na senilidade é a curta memória. Por isso, deixe sua página consistente. Em todas as etapas, menu no lugar do menu, rodapé no lugar do rodapé, *sidebar* no lugar da *sidebar*. Tanto em posição como em conteúdo, contraste, cor e tamanho.

Adote também uma consistência com outros sites que seu público costuma acessar. Isso diminui a curva de aprendizagem do seu site ou app.

### Simplicidade

Para diminuir a sobrecarga cognitiva e aumentar a atenção, isto é, deixar que o usuário pense menos para executar a tarefa proposta, sua página deve ser simples. A navegação deve ser a menos confusa possível.

1. Tire qualquer distração.
2. Remova ações desnecessárias ou [agrupe-as](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/14f08efe-eb50-4a31-9eef-a4f8a2e03643/cognitive-overload-image9-large-opt.jpg).
3. Corte a quantidade excessiva de [estímulos da página](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/544f2ffe-9469-4cba-986b-fa26055015dc/cognitive-overload-image1.gif).

[image]

Uma recomendação de leitura: [Don't Make Me Think do Steve Krug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321965515) (Não Me Faça Pensar).

### Recuperação de erros

Sim, usuários cometem erros. Porém, é sua obrigação dar uma alternativa para que eles possam revertê-los.

Os problemas cognitivos podem incluir uma dificuldade de resolver problemas. Se você tem um formulário e um erro de validação aconteceu, deixe claro como o usuário se recupera desse erro. Se o usuário clicou um um link errado, deixe claro como voltar para onde ele estava.

1. Crie mensagens de erro que digam o que há de errado e dê uma forma de corrigir.
2. Tente prever os erros do usuário, assim como o Google diz "você quis dizer...?".
3. Alerte o usuário sobre ações irreversíveis como excluir um arquivo.

## Problemas motores

### Teclado

Muitas pessoas com problemas motores utilizam ferramentas para ajudá-las, chamadas de *assistive technology*. Tenha certeza de que seu site funciona sem um mouse, somente com o teclado.

Links, botões, campos de formulário devem poder receber foco com <kbd>Tab</kbd>, por exemplo. Deve haver alguma indicação de foco nesses elementos também.

### Precisão

Não deixe que seus formulários e elementos demandem precisão. Por exemplo: um checkbox deve poder ser clicado fora da "bolinha".

Deixe espaço suficiente entre os campos de formulário, e de preferência, um campo seguido do outro.

[image]

> Entre as idades 55 e 65, a coordenação entre visão e mão, e habilidades motoras tendem a diminuir e isso pode deixar mais difícil interagir com as interfaces. O mouse é um problema particular de usuários com problemas motores, já que fica difícil clicar nos alvos da interface, mover entre elementos da interface e responder à alvos na tela. [(fonte)](https://usabilitygeek.com/ux-design-thinking-senior-citizen-user/)

Sua página deve ser totalmente adaptada para dispositivos touch, pois é mais fácil para essas pessoas utilizarem essa tecnologia ao invés de um mouse.

---

Os sites do governo brasileiro são adaptados para pessoas com problemas de visão, e outros tópicos da acessibilidade. Aqui vai um [guia de acessibilidade (eMAG)](http://emag.governoeletronico.gov.br) escrito pelo próprio órgão federal.

Alguns especialistas em UX falaram sobre o assunto, e vou deixar os links aqui:

- [Designing for Senior Citizens](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/05/designing-for-senior-citizens-organizing-your-work-schedule.php)
- [New Heuristics for Understanding Older Adults as Web Users](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4UlBnHFGSaMM2U3Zjk2MzAtNjhjMS00ZGUyLWExYTQtNDAzNzU0MzU5ZDE2/view?hl=en)
- [UX Design Thinking From A Senior Citizen’s Perspective](https://usabilitygeek.com/ux-design-thinking-senior-citizen-user/)
- [Web Usability and Aging](https://www.usability.gov/get-involved/blog/2008/12/aging-and-usability.html)

Comment: Vini muito obrigado pela resposta, foi bem esclarecedor

Answer (score 2):

Adicionando mais alguns itens importantes, não comentados na resposta anterior...

Há algumas coisas que podem ser evitadas porque um idoso possívelmente não entenda, como estrangeirismos e ícones, por exemplo, "Dar um like", "Assistir a live" e o ícone de compartilhar ([image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui])

Mesmo fazendo um site com todos os itens de acessibilidade, ainda sim é importante ter um bom SAC, já havia comentado:

> Começar com um modal bem grande dizendo "Qualquer dúvida nos pergunte no número X" e ter alguém sempre para atender, se possível, de graça a ligação (para quem liga)

Seria o ideal, mas nem sempre é viável, há algumas alternativas (que também podem ser usadas em conjunto), como o chat, tanto com um atendente como com uma IA. Mas deve-se tomar cuidado, pessoalmente, já usei chats com IA que eram inúteis, nunca resolveu um único problema, se for só atrapalhar é melhor nem ter, felizmente havia uma opção "Falar com um atendente". Outra opção é uma central de ajuda, como a do [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), onde é possível tirar as dúvidas mais frequentes

Comment: Legal as observações, algumas são pontos essenciais do `ux writing` ;)